# Enter/Return command in Shell script

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to issue an external shell command via python script. The external command prompts user to type 'Y' and hit enter to proceed further. How do I write the command in python script in a loop so that it does not prompts the user in every loop. I can grab a coffee and step out instead of sitting in front of the PC and hit Y every time I see the prompt.

My python script loops like

```
<for loop:>
    os.system(<External Command>)
```

I tried echoing "Y\n" but did not work.

Comment: Well...if all you're doing is accepting input from the user, is there any reason not to do that through `raw_input` or `input` if you're on Python 3.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `yes` command, the following code should do what you want:

```
<for loop:>
    os.system('yes Y | <external command>')
```

more info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/python/pexpect/). You can write a script to watch for your command's output, and respond appropriately.